# accessing exported json object created with mongoose node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I am taking first steps with Node.JS and came across a weird issue i cant figure out. I have this `events` object from the `upcoming_events.js` file i am exporting like this:

```
 module.exports = function(passport, FacebookStrategy, config, mongoose) {    
        var fbEvent = new mongoose.Schema({
            eventID: String,
            eventName: String,
            eventPic: String,
            rsvp_list: Array,
            category: String
        })

        var eventModel = mongoose.model('fbEvent', fbEvent);

        eventModel.find({}, function(err, events) {
            if (err) throw err;

            module.exports.events = events;
        })

    }
```

and in the receiving side, the file 'routes.js' i was able to access the data
like this:

```
var events = require('../data/upcoming_events.js');

router.get('/upcoming_events', securePages, function(req, res, next){
    console.log(events.events[0].eventName);//accessing data....
        res.render('upcoming_events', {title: 'Welcome to aDating - Upcoming Events'});
})
```

and the log i would get looks like this:

```
{ _id: 55aa582edeea927016d5af1c,
  eventID: '1111',
  eventName: 'Breakfast Club',
  eventPic: '4d669b',
  category: 'Party',
  __v: 0,
  rsvp_list:
   [ '12343242'
 ] }
```

so  far everything works fine but now i want to pass this data to another file ,`'proccess_data.js'` and than send it to `routes.js`. The proccess looks like this (no functionality for demonstration):

```
var events = require('../data/upcoming_events.js');
module.exports.user = events;
```

but now when i require the data from the `proccess_data.js` file and trying to access it in the same way:

```
var data= require('../data/proccess_data.js');

router.get('/upcoming_events', securePages, function(req, res, next){
    console.log(data.events[0].eventName);//accessing data....
        res.render('upcoming_events', {title: 'Welcome to aDating - Upcoming Events'});
})
```

i get the following error in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

one more detail, when i export `events` from `proccess_data.js` like this:

```
module.exports = function(passport, FacebookStrategy, config, mongoose) {
    var events = require('../data/upcoming_events.js');
    module.exports.user = events;
}
```

and access it like this in routes.js like this:

```
console.log(data.user);
```

this is what prints out:

```
{ [Function]
  events:
   [ { _id: 55aa582edeea927016d5af1c,
       eventID: '1111',
       eventName: 'TONIGHT - Andreas Henneberg // Breakfast Club',
       eventPic: '69b',
       category: 'Party',
       __v: 0,
       rsvp_list:
        [ '12343242',
          '12366662' ] },
     { _id: 55aa6a751178e94823016053,
       eventID: '2222', ...And so on...
```

any idea why is that please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

1) Export from `upcoming_events.js` - is function;

2) In module `proccess_data.js` - you export it as `user` function;

3) And in routes.js it's coming as object where key `user` is function.

So, try `data.user()[0].eventName`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the NodeJS environment a little oddly.

Firstly, You should use `module.exports` to export the main *class* of the JS file. You definitely don't (and can't) use it in a runtime (anything other than an immediately-invoked function expression) sort of way, i.e.

```
eventModel.find({}, function(err, events) {
    if (err) throw err;
    module.exports.events = events;
})
```

Secondly, all the modules that your file needs should be `require`d at the top of your JS file and, again, not in a runtime sort of way: i.e.

```
module.exports = function(passport, FacebookStrategy, config, mongoose) {
    var events = require('../data/upcoming_events.js');
    module.exports.user = events;
}
```

The second item has more caveats than the first one, but it's a good practice to start with.